# three.js order of loading resources

Tags: three.js

I have a **obj** model that I'm loading via [THREE.LoadingManager](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/LoadingManager) and a few textures. When I'm opening the page with clear cache - I'm always getting model without textures. I can see them after pressing F5. My code looks like this:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();    
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);
var textures_loaded = 0;

var id;
for (id in materials) {
    loader.load('images/' + materials[id].unique_id + '.jpg', function(t) {
        t.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
        t.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;

        var re = /images\/(\d+)\.jpg/g;
        var result = re.exec(t.image.currentSrc);

        material = materials.filter(function(obj) {
            return obj.unique_id == result[1];
        }).shift();

        material.setTexture(t);
        textures_loaded += 1;

        if (textures_loaded == materials.length) {
            mainLoop();
        }
    });
}

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load('obj/' + model.model_name, function (object) {
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                var mesh = model.meshes.filter(function(mesh) {
                    return mesh.name == child.name;
                }).shift();

                child.material.map = mesh.material.texture;
                child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate;
                child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate;
            }
        });

        scene.add(object);
    }
);
```

I'm running **mainLoop** only after all textures are loaded. But sometimes model loads faster. How can I control order of loading objects using **THREE.LoadingManager** ?. How can I show model only after everything is loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this. Have two functions responsible for loading each set of content inline. In this case the meshes will not be loaded until the materials are done loading.

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);



 function loadMaterials(materials, callback){
   var textures_loaded = 0;
   for (var id in materials) {
       loader.load('images/' + materials[id].unique_id + '.jpg', function(t) {
           t.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
           t.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;

           var re = /images\/(\d+)\.jpg/g;
           var result = re.exec(t.image.currentSrc);

           material = materials.filter(function(obj) {
               return obj.unique_id == result[1];
           }).shift();

           material.setTexture(t);
           textures_loaded += 1;

           if (textures_loaded == materials.length) {
                callback("materialsLoaded");
               //mainLoop();
           }
       });
   }
 }


var loadedMeshes = [];

function loadMeshes(meshes, callback){
  var meshes_loaded = 0;
  for(var i in meshes){
     var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
     loader.load('obj/' + model.model_name, function (object) {
       loadedMeshes.push(object);
       object.traverse(function(child) {
           if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
               //you'll need to map to the right material.
               child.material.map = mesh.material.texture;
               child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate;
               child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate;
           }
       });
       if(loadedMeshes.length == meshes.length){
         callback("meshesLoaded");
       }
     };
   }
 }


var materials = ["material1", "material2"];
var meshes = ["mesh1.obj", "mesh2.obj"];

function onLoad(){
    for(var i in loadedMeshes){
      scene.add(loadedMeshes[i]);
    }
    mainLoop();
}

function init(){
  loadMaterials(materials, function(t){
    console.log(t);
    loadMeshes(meshes, function(t){
      console.log(t);
      onLoad(t);
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can indeed use the loading manager more discretely, but I find I need then to also write another manager to track when dependencies are met before instantiating geometries as meshes when a simple array check will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to execute your **mainLoop** only when the document is ready, using some jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function mainLoop(){});
```

"this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received"

from [jQuery .ready event](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: HIs meshes will still have been created with an undefined material object.